# I have problem with datepicker dateDisnable

Tags: javascript, html, date, datepicker, bootstrapper

I hava a problem with use datepicker bootstrap v1.5.0

```
    var nowTemp = new Date();
 var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
 var checkin = $('.checkin').datepicker({
        todayHighlight:'TRUE',
        autoclose: true,
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            return date.valueOf() >= now.valueOf();
        },
        datesDisabled :test,
    }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
        $(this).datepicker('hide');
        if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.datepicker("getDate").valueOf()
            || !checkout.datepicker("getDate").valueOf()) {
            var newDate = new Date(ev.date);
            newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
            checkout.datepicker("update", newDate);
        }

    });
var checkout = $('.checkout').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            if (!checkin.datepicker("getDate").valueOf()) {
                return date.valueOf() >= new Date().valueOf();
            } else {
                return date.valueOf() > checkin.datepicker("getDate").valueOf();
            }
        },
        autoclose: true,
        datesDisabled :daylist,
    }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {});
```

when I choose date of my checkin input, my checkout input not display, but when i press tab and click again, it display and with error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqKI7.png)

Comment: Please share the error that you get. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears you may have syntax errors:

remove comma ","

`datesDisabled :test,`

`datesDisabled :test`

and also here:

`datesDisabled :daylist,`

`datesDisabled :daylist`